# if-else statement inside jsx not working as expected

Tags: react-native, state, jsx

I am trying to animate an image in and out when clicked using React Native reanimated, but the JSX if else condition is not working quite right. Below is the code that works, but only works when clicked for the first time. The state toggled is set to true, so when clicked again it should set the size back to the original and the image should animate back to it and vice versa.

The setup is like so:

```
export default () => {
  const newNumber = useSharedValue(100);
  const [Toggled, setToggled] = useState(false);

  const style = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      width: withSpring(newNumber.value),
      height: withSpring(newNumber.value, {  damping: 10,
      stiffness: 90, }),
      
    };
  });

onPress={() => {
          {Toggled ? newNumber.value = 100 : newNumber.value = 350; setToggled(true)}
        }}
```

The problem is when I try to add the `newNumber.Value = 100` when setting Toggled to false, it gives me an error. I try to add it like this :

```
{Toggled ? newNumber.value = 100; setToggled(false) : newNumber.value = 350; setToggled(true)}
```

Why does it accept the first one but not the second?

If I use this, it works, but can it be done the other way?

```
const isToggled = Toggled;
 
if (isToggled) {
  // alert('Is NOT Toggled');
  newNumber.value = 100;
  setToggled(false)
} else {
// alert('Is Toggled');
  newNumber.value = 350;
  setToggled(true)
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You write *it gives me an error*, which means that the very next thing from your keyboard should be the **complete, exact** error message. It's on the screen right in front of you, but we can't see that screen from here. The error message contains information that may be useful, and there is no excuse for not providing us with that information.

Comment: It says unexpected token. expected ":"

Comment: That tells you the problem. It's not expecting the `;` in your ternary operation. I don't think you can run multiple statements inside the ternary. It's `(condition) ? (true option): (false option)`, not `(condition) ? (true op); (true op2): (false op) (false op2)`

Comment: oh ok, shall i just keep using the solution that works then? There is no way with less code?

Comment: I would write it something like `{Toggled ? newNumber.value = 100 : newNumber.value = 350; setToggled(newNumber.Value == 100))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks you are just setting a value to newNumber base on `Toggled`, and then setting the `Toggled` to its opposite value. So why not do

```js
onPress={() => {
  newNumber.value = Toggled ? 100 : 350
  setToggled(prev=>!prev)
}}
```

Comment: Works a charm, but can you exaplain how the prev=>!prev works please as I can not see where it holds any information or anything?

Comment: the setter from useState accepts a value or a function that will set that value. If you use a function to set that value, then the the first parameter of that function will be the current value of the state. `!` flips boolean values.